# Can you write UTF-8, UTF-16 and std::wstring representation of "U+9FA5 (龥)" and "U+0041 (A)" unicode characters?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, wstring

Please specify if there is a difference in representation between Windows and Linux machines (*like std::wstring consuming 4 bytes in Linux and 2 bytes in Windows*).
And please also specify endianness if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean those are already unicode characters.

Comment: ^ I didn't say something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can't. But [this site](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) can.

Comment: I very nice site which clearly illustrate binary codes for UTF-8 and UTF-16. Adding up the fact that Martin York mensioned, std::wstring being only a container type, my question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

utf-16BE which is the code page used inside the MS office family of products will store all characters as 2 bytes and is pretty much identical to the "standard" part of the Unicode character set.

Linux is probably using utf-8 which will store standard ASCII characters in a single byte *but* may store other unicode characters in two , three or four bytes, depending on the unicode code point. As the left most bits are taken up with flags to indicate its not ascii and and how far into a multibyte character you are. (The idea being that you can jump into a utf-8 string at  a random byte and be able to find the start of the character you are in.)

For most of the far eastern character sets which have high code points in unicode proper (as used by Java) is usually more efficient in space and processing time than UTF-8.

Comment: I doubt Linux uses UTF-8 in the wchar_t. It is more likely to be UTF-32

Comment: Good point! I was thinking about how they looked on output as the *nix stream classes usually convert to the local character encoding when they write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
int main()
{
    std::wstring  data1 = L"U+9FA5 (\0x9FA5)";
    std::wstring  data2 = L“U+0041 (A)";
}
```

The wstring is just a container of wchar_t objects.
There is no implied encoding of the characters (it just stores what you put it).

Windows wchar_t is currently 2 bytes so it can probably only store UTF-16 characters.
Linus   wchar_t is usually 4 bytes. So it can use an encoding of UTF-16 or UTF-32. Though it most normal situations these overlap and top half is just all zero (exceptions of course are code-points not on the BMP or surrogate pairs).

Note: UTF-8 characters are not normally used internally (though they can be) in an application as they are not fixed width. But it is extremely useful for transport and storage because of its compressibility (and backwards compatibility with ASCII does not hurt).

Note: C/C++ does not preclude the use of other encoding formats for its strings.

Comment: UTF-8 *is* used internally in GNOME(glib) and I think glib is totally normal. Also, Win32 uses UTF-16 which is not fixed.

Comment: @upriser: Of course GNOME allows you to manipulate UTF-8 But gnome is not an application it is a set of libraries (Windowing Meta layer) on which applications are built. UTF-16 is fixed size for all practical purposes. Apart from surrogate pairs all code points are 16 bits. Surrogate pairs are used to define points not on the BMP and thus in reality not used often. SO yes technically not fixed width but most people treat it as fixed width (which is a mistake).